# Converting Date time (7/19/2017 0:00) into YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z in Python

Tags: datetime

I am trying to convert something like 7/19/2017 0:00 to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z. Does anyone know how to do something like in Python?

I have tried to do this:

```
import datetime


time_str = "7/19/2017 0:00"
dt_aware = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(dt_aware.isoformat('T'))
```

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')

print dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

You could use [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) provided here to format the date with required format.